# How do I add a variable to itself in Csh

Tags: unix, csh

Hi i am trying to set a variable equal to itself plus another variable so if I do:

    `set lvt_count = 0
    set lvt = 1
    set lvt_count = $lvt_count + $lvt`

It should return a value for lvt_count, but I am getting a set:variable name must begin with letter error for some reason. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In [csh](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=csh&sektion=1&apropos=0&manpath=FreeBSD+13-current#REFERENCE)
, you don't use `set` to do arithmetic. Instead use `@`:

```
set v1 = 1
set v2 = 2
@ v1 = $v1 + $v2
echo $v1
```